# waitress+flask+gcloud how to set it up server

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, flask, gcloud, waitress

I have been trying to deploy a basic app to google engine app(because Azure is an extortion) for the past few days, I have learned that Gunicode does not work on windows system and that the alternative is waitress. I read all the answers related to the subject here, before I posted this question!!!

So I have been trying different setups, reading about it and I still can't get it running. My field is data science, but deployment seems to be obligatory nowadays. If someone can help me out please, it would be very appreciated.

app.py file

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
from waitress import serve


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    name = request.args.get("name")
    if name == None:
        name = "Reinhold"
    return render_template("index.html", name=name)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #app.run(debug=True)
    serve(app, host='0.0.0.0', port=8080)
```

Gcloud app deploy will look for the gunicode to start the deployment which will be at the app.yaml file, I tried different setups there and I ended up setting it up None as Flask will look for an alternative in my humble view. Though I still think that would be better to setup the waitress server there.

app.yaml file

```
runtime: python37
#entrypoint: None
entrypoint: waitress-serve --listen=*:8080 serve:app
```

GCloud also will look for an appengine_config.py file where it will find the dependencies(I think)

```
from google.appengine.ext import vendor

vendor.add('venv\Lib')
```

The requirements.txt file will be the following:

```
astroid==2.3.3
autopep8==1.4.4
Click==7.0
colorama==0.4.3
dominate==2.4.0
Flask==1.1.1
Flask-Bootstrap==3.3.7.1
Flask-WTF==0.14.2
isort==4.3.21
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.10.3
lazy-object-proxy==1.4.3
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
mccabe==0.6.1
pycodestyle==2.5.0
pylint==2.4.4
six==1.13.0
typed-ast==1.4.1
visitor==0.1.3
waitress==1.4.2
Werkzeug==0.16.0
wrapt==1.11.2
WTForms==2.2.1
```

In the google console I could access the log view to see what was going wrong during the deployment and that is what I got from the code I shared here.

```
{
 insertId: "5e1e9b4500029d71f92c1db9"  
 labels: {…}  
 logName: "projects/bokehflaskgcloud/logs/stderr"  
 receiveTimestamp: "2020-01-15T04:55:33.288839846Z"  
 resource: {…}  
 textPayload: "/bin/sh: 1: exec: None: not found"  
 timestamp: "2020-01-15T04:55:33.171377Z"  
}
```

If someone could help solve this, that would be great because google seems to be a good alternative to deploy some work. Azure and VScode have a good interaction so it isnt as hard to deploy it there, but the cost of it after the trial is insane.

That is what I get once I try to deploy the application.

```
Error: Server Error
The server encountered an error and could not complete your request.
Please try again in 30 seconds.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

easily run your flask app using Gunicorn:

```
runtime: python37
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT main:app
```

you need to add **gunicorn** to your **requirments.txt**

check [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#application_startup) on how to define application startup in python 3

make sure that you run your app using flask run method, in case you want to test your app locally:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='127.0.0.1', port=8080, debug=True)
```

Comment: Spot on Methkal, that was a simple and elegant solution. In case someone had the same issue and is wondering here.
Whatever you named your application be: main/app/myapp make sure that you add it as below, in my case my routes were under app.py
```
entrypoint: gunicorn -b :$PORT app:app
```

Answer (score 0):

1. appengine_config.py is not used in Python 3. The Python 2 runtime uses this file to install client libraries and provide values for constants and "hook functions". The Python 3 runtime doesn't use this file.
2. the app.py file there is no mention of flask library

Please add following import at line 2.

```
from flask import Flask, request, render_template
```

Comment: Dude I just forgot to add it on this question, the app would not even run if I didnt have it. I will delete the appengine_config.py to see what happens. The issue is the path for the server.

Comment: hi @Vikram , is there any limitations that prevents you from using **gunicorn** ?

Comment: Hi @Vikram. Yep. It is running on python 3.7 gunicorn will just be used by python 2x, though I tried to use waitress, wsgi server. Nothing has work still.